# how to call a vue component outside of instance in javascript?

Tags: webpack, vue.js

I developed some vue component (grid,popup,layout..) by webstorm with (vue-cli..webpack ...) .

My development environment:
webstorm + webpack + vue-cli

Now i want to know how i can use that in a javascript?

i can call it like this 
In main js , i write ..
import Grid from './Grid'
window.$grid = Grid
and i use webpack package app.js   (mycode and others..)

My demo.html

```
1.<script src=app.js> <script src=demo.js>
2.<div id="showdiv"></div>
3.
```

demo.js

```
$('showdiv').append('<grid :options="options"></grid>')
var grid = window.$grid
var gridvue = new Vue({
      el: '#showdiv',
      data: {
        options: options
      },
      components: {grid}
    })
```

But if i use more component.vue i must create the same numbers of new Vue
I dont think it's a good way to use vue outside.

I'm very grateful  to who answer my question , thanks!
sorry for my english...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

webpack.config.js

```
output: {
    path: config.build.assetsRoot,
    filename: utils.assetsPath('js/[name].js'),
    library: 'senyint',//package name senyint  window.senyint
    libraryTarget: 'umd',//package type umd
    umdNamedDefine: true,
    chunkFilename: utils.assetsPath('js/[id].js')
  },
```

main.js

```
exports.scom = {
  Bug, Hello, Grid, Div, Button, Loading
}
```

demo.html

```
<script src='/dist/js...all'>
//we can call the component   
window.senyint.scom.Grid  like this..
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have become a little confused about how components work in `Vue`, in your case you can simply create [single file components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html) with each component registering it's own dependencies:

**Gridvue.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
     <grid :options="options"></grid>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Grid from './Grid.vue

export default {
   components: {
     Grid // register grid so it can now be used inside the component
   },
   props: ['options']
}
</script>
```

Now when you want to use gridvue you import it in to a separate component, for this example I'll use the main entry point of your app called `App.vue`:

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <grid-vue :options="options"></grid-vue>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import GridVue from './GridVue.vue

export default {
   components: {
     GridVue // register GridVue so it can now be used inside the component
   },
   data(){
     return {
       options: {}
     }
   }
}
</script>
```

Now you mount `App.vue` to the main vue instance:

```
import App from './App.vue';

new Vue({
    name: "App",
    render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app');
```

And in your `HTML` you simply have:

```
<div id="app"></div>
```

Now you have one main vue instance that serves up your components. Notice that I'm not attaching anything to `window` or using `jQuery` to attempt to inject anything into the view port, I'm simply building up my components one at a time and registering them in the components I need them in.

Comment: Maybe i didnt discribe my question.  i know  vue how to work in SPA. but now package some componentvue.vue for javaer use.It's some component.vue(grid.vue layout.vue popup.vue ).And i must use it in jsp.html.js. For example: javaer write a business page with a grid a popup and a layout. how can they includ my package ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you're attempting to do, could you give a simplified example on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: see it https://github.com/hpym365/vue-element  It's my project. It can run with npm run dev. But i want to use the project like a plugin. In other project,just import it , and use the component vue of the project. Thanks